# What's the point of the suffrage and vox populi badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

What's the point of the suffrage and vox populi badges? I agree that it is good to incentivize engagement, but aren't these badges likely to lead people to run through votes rapidly just to get the badges?

`Suffrage: Used 30 votes in a day`

`Vox Populi: Used the maximum 40 votes in a day`

EDIT: @JWLim made a good point in the comments.  Why are both badges needed?  Seems redundant.

Comment: As long as they give reasonable votes it is a valuable experience. I recently ran out of votes for the first time when I went on a killing/closing spree. When the limit what exhausted I felt like I had won the game :)

Comment: PS, [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Downvotes here tend to indicate disagreement with a particular suggestion/proposal instead of the question itself being bad.

Comment: use 30 votes mean to cast votes on any posts, right?

Answer (score 42):

You'd think so.

And yet there are nearly as many folks with [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard) as there are with Suffrage, even though by rights Suffrage should be a lot easier to get.

Go figure...

Comment: wow - those are really easy to get.  the most recent one awarded took 1 min to achieve.  I'm in awe of him.

Comment: But what's the point of having **both** Suffrage and Vox Populi? Why not just have Vox Populi, since that's for the maximum?

Comment: yeah, that's... not gonna last, @Plutonix.

Comment: To reward folks who use all of their votes and then further encourage them to go the extra mile to vote on questions, @JWLim. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/

Comment: @Shog9 That still doesn't explain the need for two votes-per-day badges. Suffrage is awarded for 30 votes in a day. Vox is for 40 in a day. "To reward folks who use all of their votes", Vox is sufficient enough, no need for a pre-using-all-daily-votes badge (which is really what Suffrage is). And to "encourage them to go the extra mile to vote on questions", we've got the gold Electorate badge for that. There's also the silver Civic Duty to further encourage users to vote.

Comment: @Shog9 there are gobs of bad awards in there...60 rep, 6Q, 6A?  Rep gets rolled back from fraud, but revoking the hat is manual apparently?

Comment: If you find something blatantly wrong, flag it @Plutonix. Custom message, put "shog" in it somewhere.

Comment: @JWLim There is no *need*, other than the need for  backward compatibility. [Suffrage existed for a long time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228091/259867) before Vox appeared. If the badges were designed from scratch at this time, surely there wouldn't be both of these.

Comment: ...heck, if we were designing this from scratch, there wouldn't be *two different votes per day thresholds...*

Answer (score 29):

Both badges are needed in order to encourage people to **vote for both questions and answers**; there was a tendency at one point for people to just vote for answers and leave the questions themselves a bit unloved. Since you can't vote for 40 answers in a single day (I think 30 is the maximum there) having the badge dangling there helps generate Good Behavior; it <s>tempts</s> nudges those people who are inveterate badge hunters to do the Right Thing without forcing them to do so.

Which is the whole point of the badge system in the first place.