# Why is the Mortarboard badge not removed after serial upvoting reversal?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Looking at the recently awarded [Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard) badges I noticed that quite a few low-rep users are getting this badge. I became curious and started to poke around the profile of a few of those users and saw that they received the badge due to serial upvoting. Although the serial upvoting was detected and reversed by the system, the badge seems to stick.

I am pretty sure that this is not how the badge is supposed to work (although it might answer the question in a [recent Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258717/1054378) why so many Mortarboard badges are awarded). Is there a specific reason why Mortarboard is not removed after serial upvoting reversal?

To provide some examples: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2337214/tiago-vieira-dos-santos?tab=reputation), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1660031/vishnu-y?tab=reputation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3458261/sabari?tab=reputation). Feel free to remove the links if you feel this is fingerpointing.

---

**EDIT**

The last sentence in animuson's answer is too much. I can't let this stand without pointing out that my motiviation for asking this question is **NOT** jealousy or something. My "piece of mind" is not at all disturbed by those guys having a badge or three more than they might have earned via normal means. I just wanted to point out a potential bug that, for some mysterious reason, might have gone unnoticed. As it turns out, this is not the case. Case closed.

Comment: The association bonus isn't reversed either, which is pretty bad too. (But badges are never removed automatically, except for tag badges.)

Answer (score -17, accepted):

Because Stack Exchange policy is that normal badges are never revoked.

In extreme circumstances where a user has received many badges through unfavorable means, the Stack Exchange team *can* revoke them all. But for a simple bronze badge... it's *just* a bronze badge.

The Mortarboard badge, as a bronze badge, is meant to teach users about the daily reputation cap, which is most often noticed by users for the first time after reaching 200 reputation on a single day.

My best advice is stop worrying about other users and their badges. Badges mean absolutely nothing. The only one that will even gain you additional privileges is a gold tag badge. There is no harm in letting someone keep a bronze badge, and absolutely nothing is achieved by revoking it.

Comment: Sorry, but *it's just a bronze badge* doesn't apply for [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) if the same is implemented even there.

Comment: If it is "just" a bronze badge, why is it difficult to remove?

Comment: @TLama If someone were to cheat their way to Legendary, they have bigger problems than a badge revocation.

Comment: But serial voting gap will count to their way, won't it ?

Comment: @TLama If they get serial voted on the last day, sure they'll get a gold badge for hitting the 150 mark. But no, reversed votes cease to count towards their total days for that badge. 150 serial voting reversals will not gain you the badge. You'll still be sitting there with only a Mortarboard.

Comment: @TLama Even if you manage to cheat successfully every single day and not get caught, it still requires almost half a year of hard work to get the Legendary badge. If someone wants a gold badge that badly, it's a lot less work to go for Fanatic.

Comment: Accepting your answer, but not +1 because 1) I find it doubtful that badges are supposed to be teaching devices. 2) I find your advice to stop worrying about badges slightly ridiculous. Are we supposed to ignore badges if we see them on other users? They _are_ called "badges" for a reason. And 3) "badges mean absolutely nothing" - yeah, I guess that's true for those zen masters living in the ivory tower of altruism.

Comment: @herzbube Doubtful how? Bronze badges *are* teaching devices. They're explicitly designed to be easily attainable because they're meant to teach users about the basic functionalities of the site. No, you're not supposed to *ignore* badges, but you're definitely not supposed to obsess over them. I, personally, *never* look at the number of badges a user has. It means nothing at all to me. But even for someone who does consider badges useful, what is *one more* bronze badge? A 5 instead of a 4? Does that really make all that much of a difference?

Comment: Accepted but -20 ... gg @animuson. Have a +1 :p

Comment: Harmless or not, it is a bug, and so should be removed. ALL bugs should be removed, no matter how small or hard to get. If nothing else, because we can't know what tomorrow will bring. Ten years from now, SO may decide to change the importance placed on badges, and the bug may be long forgotten. It may also be nearly impossible to fix by then. If all that happens and the wrong person rediscovered it, the consequences would be devastating. Murphy's law... EDIT: I realize it implements a business policy, but I stand by my comment. It is a policy that severely limits SO's future options.

Comment: @Nathan Except we do not consider it to be a bug and we have zero interest in doing anything about this situation. There is no chance this will be revisited in the future.