# Mortarboard badge is awarded due to bounty award?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

I was looking through my badges, and was surprised to find that I have the [mortarboard badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=2446155). It was awarded to me on August 11, 2013.

My only reputation gain on that day was a bounty award of 200 reputation. Bounties are [not subject to the daily reputation limit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), so technically I should not have gotten this badge, as I did not reach the limit. There is no record of any other reputation gains or losses on that day.

Since [badges are not ever revoked after they have been awarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258768/2446155), I am not surprised that I still have this badge.

So is it a bug that a bounty award caused me to receive the badge?

And is this bug even still present today?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Not one that any SO user ever complained about before, mind you :)  Let's call it a feature.

Comment: Note you'd also get it from accepted answers which also don't contribute to the cap

Comment: @HansPassant: The badge title doesn't state you need to hit the cap. The title tells you you need to earn 200 points, *and educates you about the daily cap*. What confuses people is that they think you need to hit the cap, therefor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design.

The Mortarboard badge is awarded when you receive 200 points or more in a day; reaching it via 140 points from upvotes and 60 points from accepts also counts, for example.

From the [Meta.SE badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731):

> #### Mortarboard
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day

The only bug here then is that the (deliberately concise) badge text can perhaps be misread a little too easily.

The goal of the badge is to educate you about the *existence* of the reputation cap; that goal was met as you clearly know about the cap. But note that the badge description **doesn't claim** you need to hit the cap:

> Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day

You earned 200 reputation. 200 rep is also the daily maximum *for upvotes and accepted suggested edits*, but the assumption that you actually need *hit* the cap is yours.

Comment: `(the daily maximum)` threw me off