# How can I see my meta reputation history?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

I recently earned the [Mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=2446155) on this Meta for earning 200 reputation in one day.

The [*What's Meta?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page states:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is
>   the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly),
>   though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to
>   participate on meta.

Since I earned the Mortarboard badge, I must be earning reputation on meta *somewhere*. I'm supposed to believe that **meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow**, but there must be some way the *real* meta reputation is being recorded.

I'm interested to see how much reputation I would have on Meta if the old system (meta being completely separate from main) was still in use. More specifically, I'd like to be able to review my reputation history, just like in the `Reputation` tab on my profile page on the main site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167648/make-voting-activity-on-your-posts-available-on-site-metas-what-you-would-get-f

Comment: There's also the Meta equivalent, [participation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation) (though it has nothing to do with the theoretical per-site meta reputation).

Comment: Another related post: [“Mortarboard” continues to be awarded on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251249).

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a reputation history on any child-meta, like this one.

Reputation is inherited from the main site (Stack Overflow in this case).

Badges are something different. You will note that they are based on **scores** and not reputation.

Comment: The Mortarboard badge description on meta says it's rewarded for earning 200 rep, though. So, the description seems inaccurate, in that case.

Comment: That differs from [the main site behavior](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260075/2446155) since that badge is based solely on reputation points on the main site.

Comment: [An old MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/should-i-really-have-been-awarded-mortarboard-on-a-per-site-meta)

Answer (score 5):

So out of curiosity, I wanted to know how much reputation I would earn if you really *could* earn rep normally on Meta, just like on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Thus, I wrote this [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/215919/virtual-meta-reputation-for-user-x?UserId=456814) to calculate my "virtual" Meta reputation:

```sql
SELECT
  -- p.Id AS [Post Link],
  -- v.VoteTypeId,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 1 THEN 15 -- Accepts
    WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 THEN 5  -- Question upvotes
    WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 THEN 10 -- Answer upvotes
    WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 3 THEN -2 -- Receive downvotes
  END) AS Reputation,
  COUNT(CASE v.VoteTypeId WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS Accepts,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 THEN 1 END) AS QUpVotes,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN v.VoteTypeId = 2 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END) AS AUpVotes,
  COUNT(CASE v.VoteTypeId WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS DownVotes
FROM Posts p
  INNER JOIN Votes v ON p.Id = v.PostId
  INNER JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
WHERE v.VoteTypeId IN (1,2,3) -- accepts,ups,downs
  AND p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
```

#### Some points to note

1. The query is not smart enough (yet) to take into account daily reputation caps, so it will possibly over-estimate your virtual reputation.
2. I forgot to take into account that on main sites, you earn +2 rep when you accept an answer, but that's a very tiny amount of rep anyways, so it's not going to make much difference for really active Meta members.
3. I also forgot to take into account the fact that you lose -1 rep every time that you downvote *someone else's* answer. Considering how much more freely downvotes flow here on Meta (compared to the main site), that could actually add up to quite a bit of rep loss. Again, however, if you're really active on Meta, you probably have a ton of virtual rep anyways, so so what? `:P`

Comment: TODO: implement a [Meta virtual reputation league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta)! `:P`

Comment: 4. You forgot to take into account deleted posts. 5. (Not important to you I think) You did not take into spam/offensive penalties on post deletion. Anyway, good one.

Comment: @Deduplicator why would I need to take into account deleted posts? They don't count for rep, and they aren't included by [data.se].

Comment: Hm, should have said cannot take into account: If they are old enough and ... rep is preserved on deletion.

Comment: @Deduplicator oh, right, I forgot about that. Boy, this sure is complicated! `:P`