# auto vote-fraud reversal does not negate epic / legendary count

Tags: bug, voting-fraud, daily-reputation-badges

A few days ago I got a lot of rep at once, despite not providing any new content that day. I assumed (and rightly so) vote-fraud and the points got removed the next day. So far - so fine.

But then I looked at my 'Epic' tracer and it had increased by one for that day. That seems like a bug. Points that are reduced because of vote-fraud reversal should not count against the Epic / Legendary badges. I propose that this will be enacted retroactively.

Please note that I did not initiate the fraud, I assume my account was used to mask the original target.

It seems this question has been [answered here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258749/881272), so this is - very unsatisfying to me - by design.