# Are there any users with over 50,000 rep, who were caught using sock-puppets?

Tags: discussion, users, sock-puppets

Are there any high rated Stack Overflow users who were ever caught with a sock-puppet or two? If yes, what kinds of actions were taken against such high reputed users?

Comment: We are not going to discuss fraudulent accounts, no. You don't need to know this.

Comment: @Martijn spoken like a true puppeteer. (:P)

Comment: @mega6382: why do you want to know? People of all levels can fall for temptations, we deal with them just the same.

Comment: What's the point of sock puppetry when you can't reach 50,000 rep with it? Or even 330,000? I mean that's the *goal*, right?

Comment: Also, having a sock puppet account isn't an issue as long as that secondary account and the primary account don't interact on the same questions/answers (e.g. voting on each other)

Comment: On a site like Stack Overflow, 50k isn't an impressive amount. The odds that at least one 50k+ user has been caught are almost certainly greater than zero.

Comment: @Tom The rule is, you can't have a second account to do things that your primary account can't do. That includes not only voting on each other, but also evading system-imposed restrictions, like automatic bans.

Comment: @CodyGray How about having separate accounts for separate SE sites?

Comment: @CodyGray Correct. I knew that, but haven't mentioned that for very specific reasons ... :P.

Comment: @mega6382 That should be fine. You could even have separate accounts on Stack Overflow, each for one main language tag.

Comment: Yes, separate accounts for different sites is fine. For example, you might not want your [beer drinking habit](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) connected with your Stack Overflow Jobs profile. ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray What about rate limited actions (Flags, CV, Votes) - how careful would one have to be not to go over one accounts rates?

Comment: @SebastianProske It's a violation of the rules to use multiple accounts to get around rate limits, yes.  Creating a bunch of accounts so that you can get more than the allotted votes/flags/etc. is not appropriate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, I'm sure there has been.

The same actions that would have been taken against anyone else caught operating sockpuppets: the votes are invalidated, the sockpuppet accounts are removed, and the user is warned. Depending on the severity and the moderators' judgment, the user found operating the sockpuppets may also be temporarily suspended. Repeated offenses virtually always carry a suspension.

Reputation does not exempt you from penalties when you break the rules.

Comment: This is the question everyone wants to ask but I'm brave enough to do so: Have you ever been caught breaking the rules?

Comment: @rene No, I have not yet been caught. Wait...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question

Comment: heh yesterday I saw how merging a sock cleared a rules violation suspension they had. "You were suspended for rule violations but now that we additionally found that you are a sock of another account you are forgiven" (I can pass IDs of the sock and master via flag on this answer if you're curious about how it went)

Comment: [A candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756246). The picture is from *"[The Wolf of Wall Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(2013_film)#Plot)"*, 1 h 40 min 08 and 1 h 40 min 25.

Comment: I'm curious, would the system take away badges earned due to rep gain through sock puppets? I'd read earlier that all badges other than tag badges are permanent.

Comment: @NisargShah they won't be.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258768/4099593