# Will Mortarboard badge get taken back?

Tags: discussion, badges

For example, I get 200 reputation some day and earn this badge. But next day the OP withdraw the accepted answer. Will this badge get taken back?

Comment: Only tag badges get removed, you keep all other badges even if you no longer qualify for them.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258749/4099593

Comment: Regular badges are forever. No, it'll not be taken back.