# Value of a "moderator eligible" badge

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, badge-request

Recent [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) announcement reports  moderator criteria for Stack Overflow includes:

> For the Stack Overflow election, candidates must have all the following badges:
> Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy, Convention

... among other non-badge requirements.

---

To help quickly identify those eligible (and to alert a user that they are now badge qualified for election<sup>*1</sup>), I suggest SO consider a *moderator eligible* (or a terser name) badge that is granted when one earns all (currently 4) badge requirements.

---

<sup>*1</sup> I'd think notifying a user that they have met these requirements would encourage participation at an earlier time than only near election time.

---

Edit] This idea here is not about my eligibly, which I know as 3 of  4 badges earned.  It is about quickly identifying others and alerting when one first becomes eligible.

Comment: There is already a message that tells you if you are eligible or not at the bottom of the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/): https://i.stack.imgur.com/unYzI.png

Comment: @Fastnlight I added a pic of the bottom of the election page yet did not see "message that tells you if you are eligible or not".  Your thoughts?

Comment: It clearly says "You need all of the following badges to nominate yourself as a candidate". I don't know about you, but to me, that looks like a message telling you that you aren't eligible. As a bonus, it even tells you why!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you [are missing a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention?userid=2410359). That's what the message tells you at the bottom of your screenshot. Compare with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb1Sy.png

Comment: @Fastnlight The election page simply list requirements.  It does not inform me _directly_ if I am qualified.  Yes I can look up my badges and see I have 3 of the 4.  Yet this issue here is not about me.  I see it more about simplifying the research needed to nominate others.

Comment: You cannot nominate others, @chux-ReinstateMonica , only yourself, so that point is moot.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for posting that pic.  I do already know I  have 3 of 4.   Yet again, the reason for this post in not about me, but to 1) rapidly ID others who are eligible and 2) to alert new folks when they become eligible.

Comment: not yet, anyway,

Comment: Um... yes it does. In your screenshot and mine, it *directly* tells us that we aren't eligible. For me, it tells me I don't have enough rep. For you, it tells you that you don't have all the required badges. Compare to VLAZ's screenshot, it *directly* tells him he is eligible and provides the nomination link.

Comment: @ThomA "cannot nominate others," -> thanks for that info - something I did not fully realize.  Of course I can suggest to someone whom I think is good to consider.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica then I don't get why you posted a picture of the election page after you were told the election page told you if you were qualified and then asked for thoughts. I was under the impression you didn't realise the election page *was* telling you whether you were qualified. If you already have this information, I don't understand why you wanted to even discuss that piece of information.

Comment: Why does it matter for you to be able to identify others that are eligible, @chux-ReinstateMonica ? As for making the user themselves aware, if a user hasn't obtained those badges they are unlikely to be a good candidate for the community, as they don't curate. The only one I *might* question is [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention), but only because Meta isn't as active as it once was. They should, however, have had activity on Meta.

Comment: *"Of course I can suggest to someone whom I think is good to consider."* If the user hasn't considered it already, it's unlikely a good option for them; moderating is a thankless and time consuming role.

Comment: @VLAZ " why you posted a picture of the election page after you were told the election page told you if you were qualified" --> Yes the pic has "You need all of the following badges to nominate yourself as a candidate: Strunk & White, Civic Duty, Deputy, and Convention", yet I read that as a generic text that applies to everyone.  It did not say something like "you still need  Convention to nominate yourself" Which would had more clearly indicted that text was customized for me.  Still - the above idea was not about "am I qualified" but to more easily find out who is and alert new folk.

Comment: @VLAZ  Since "cannot nominate others," is also in play (something alien to me a _nominate_ in my experience is to nominate someone else.) it reduces the value of the first point of this idea.

Comment: @ThomA Agree about the challenges of moderating.  Yet a suggestion to someone to consider running is the support one may need.   A user may have considered it and seeing support move to the next step.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've never been in an election IRL where I also had to nominate the person running in the election. A *party* might nominate somebody, for example, to run for mayor. And it'd be a member of that party. I sincerely doubt it's somebody who wasn't aware or wasn't willing to run. Also independent candidates would nominate themselves for mayoral elections.

Comment: @ThomA I do not disagree about nominating oneself.  I simple thought 1) an _eligible_ badge would help identify those I could nominate (now realizing that is not an option) or suggest to someone to run  (still possible) and 2) promptly notifying candidates of that option now earned by them.  Prior elections, IMO, have not had an overabundance of candidates and I wanted to see how the community thought about the idea as I perceive it would encourage participation.

Comment: I don't think awareness is the reason for a reduction in nominees.

Comment: @ThomA True that there are many contributors to reduction in nominees.  Yet I still assert that once one earns the required badges, having a notification that one has met that badge election requirement would foster election considerations - perhaps by other form than a _badge_.  As to if a new eligible member is a _good candidate_, that is what the election decides.  I am not trying to eliminate specified public hurdles, just trying to remove the need to be "in the know" barriers.

Comment: It's really not a barrier. Like I stated earlier, if the user doesn't have those badges, I would suggest they aren't a good candidate. A user that hasn't even raised 80 (helpful) flags is unlikely about to identify what moderation actions they needs to take on another user's flag, for example.

Comment: @ThomA The [barrier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429282/value-of-a-moderator-eligible-badge?noredirect=1#comment989210_429282) I refer to is **not** about the 4 badges.   For me today 2 examples: It is about little things.  it was not  knowing my _election_ page is customized to me and not of a generic nature, bigger things like knowing at SO one cannot [nominate](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/nominate) someone else.

Comment: @Fastnlight [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429282/value-of-a-moderator-eligible-badge/429283?noredirect=1#comment989180_429282) picture added [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpsgF.png) as it not central to the question.  I first added to the question as was unclear how to add to a comment.

Answer (score 13):

I do not think this is a good idea for a few reasons:

1. If a user has not had an idea they wanted to be a moderator, then awarding them a badge to tell them they are eligible is, in my opinion, not going to produce a very good candidate. After all they *just* learned about this.
2. The criteria for nomination are low: 3000 reputation and four badges. [According to this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1821640/number-of-users-who-can-run-for-mod-on-so) (courtesy of [Fastnlight](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/20153035/fastnlight)) the people who fulfil the criteria right now are 1414. If we subtract [the 25 elected moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) that leaves 1389 eligible candidates.
3. The election criteria and the whole score are *bad*. This is something that should be eliminated and the company might be making steps towards that. When exactly, I cannot say, but seems hopefully it will be. In [What would you like to change about the moderator election process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396431/what-would-you-like-to-change-about-the-moderator-election-process) staff say:

   > Candidate Score: We know that this is a piece of elections that needs updating, but we would like to have a separate conversation about this later.

   So, while this is not being addressed at the moment, it seems it is on the company's radar.

Comment: [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1821640/number-of-users-who-can-run-for-mod-on-so) takes into account the badges. At the time of writing, 1414 users are eligible to run for moderator on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Fastnlight many thanks. I was just about to try my hand at a query. I'll add it to my post. 1414 seems a lot fewer than I imagined. However, looking at the badges [Convention has only been awarded 2371 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention). The others are over 10k each, Strunk & White is even at 20k.

Comment: @VLAZ Point 1 does address my idea, yet 2 & 3 seem related to election issues in general and not so much the post.  I seemed to have touch a hot issue.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 3. in particular means that if such a badge is introduced, it might *very* quickly be obsolete. Maybe as soon as the next election. Or the election after that. Who knows.

Comment: @VLAZ OK - fair point.

Answer (score 8):

I think VLAZ has hit the main points square on the head, but a more minor detail: what happens when nomination requirements change?

It seems the company has taken some note that there are some aspects that are due for rerationalization, and it remains to be seen what might be realistic to expect versus what the powers that be are not willing to accept.

In any event, by making this into a badge you handcuff the UX into one of two bad options when the requirements do end up changing in the future:

1. **You revoke the badge from those who have already earned it under the "old" criteria, but are no longer eligible based on the updated criteria** - this seems unlikely given that [Stack Exchange's position has historically been to never remove badges except in egregious circumstances.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258768/269970)
2. **You allow users to have earned the badge to keep theirs**, which will cause significant confusion when holders of this hypothetical badge go to nominate themselves and find they cannot.

I don't personally see any pros to codifying this as a badge, but as with anything I'd be open to the idea with sufficient evidence pointing to upside impacts of such a change.

Comment: (1) Allowing “grandfathered” nominees would make changing the requirements way more moot to begin with, and at that point this post becomes way less about a badge and moreso a proposal to radically change the way eligibility is even determined for nominees in the first place. (2) These criteria apply specifically to *nomination*, so unless an even more significant change to elections is implemented where mods must be regularly re-elected by the community, I fail to see how there is any argument for one “losing eligibility” since they’ve never required a re-nomination during their tenure IIRC.

Comment: esqew, Fair point about _nomination_ - yet rules do change about mod tenure.   "never required" is a _long time_.