# Do certain badges degrade quality of site?

Tags: discussion, badges, quality-improvement

Suffrage - Encourages random voting

Disciplined - Encourages asking a good question then deleting it, robbing the site of a good question

Peer Pressure - Encourages asking a bad question then deleting it

Etc.

Comment: With a site the size of SO, people gaming the system to achieve these one time badges is a grain of sand. Most people achieve many of them before they even know they exist.

Comment: They have no point then, isn't the point in badges to encourage positively contributing?  None of these do that

Comment: They're nothing more than an introduction to a system. Earn a few badges by coincidence, learn that there's a badge system, etc

Comment: There are already 10-12 other badges that do that though.  Also, you wouldn't get suffrage until you are at least decently familiar with the site

Comment: eh, not necessarily. but even then, it promotes people using the voting tool, which is a good thing.

Comment: I'd say suffrage is one that could be justified, I can not think of a use for say Disciplined

Comment: If abused, sure, i certainly didn't earn it by purposly deleting a answer that shouldn't be deleted. Don't assume ill intent.

Comment: @AidanWelch It encourages people to delete questions that actually merit deletion.  In cases of abuse, there are systems in place to deal with it.  We do not in fact see large amounts of deletion of questions that don't merit deletion by people trying to get these badges, certainly not at levels beyond what the system's corrective systems can deal with.

Comment: Do you have evidence to suggest that this is in fact a serious problem?  How many instances of people deleting questions that should not have been deleted, and that earned the author the badge, do you have?

Comment: @Servy Wouldn't it be more likely to assume a bad question wouldn't get 3 upvotes without being reported?

Comment: @AidanWelch I wish we could assume bad questions could never attract several upvotes.  Sadly, that's not the world we live in.  It's plenty common for bad questions, or questions otherwise meriting deletion, to attract upvotes.

Comment: I earned it by deleting a correct answer that was identical to another correct answer on the same question. No need for duplicate answers :shrug:

Comment: @KevinB That is a good point in that I assumed it would be a question.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that these (or pretty much any) badges have noticeable impact on the quality of the site (ok, review badges may encourage robo-reviewing… but it does not look like the topic of this post). @AidanWelch could you please clarify if you are looking to see if badges actually impact quality of the site OR you believe it is a problem and try to come  up with a solution? (make sure to [edit] post with that clarification)

Comment: I would not assume there would be much definitive data on it, I am looking to see what others think on the matter

Comment: Complementary duplicate targets: [*Why do we have the disciplined badge?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274412/2751851); [*What's the point of the suffrage and vox populi badges?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258714/2751851)

Comment: I, for one, have earned my Disciplined badge by moving an answer to a duplicate target I found after the fact.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see those my bad, am closing as it is a duplicate

Answer (score 10):

I believe your perspective is wrong.

> Suffrage - Encourages random voting

Voting is partially pattern-driven with a twist of chaos in that a user can choose to vote arbitrarily, or vote given specific criteria.  This badge doesn't encourage one or the either; it just encourages a user to *vote*.

> Disciplined - Encourages asking a good question then deleting it, robbing the site of a good question

Votes don't establish question quality.  They only establish how the question is received by the community.  Therefore, a highly voted question which is just a bad question could be removed and would qualify for this badge.  It takes discipline to not ride the wave of the popular vote.

> Peer Pressure - Encourages asking a bad question then deleting it

I'd argue that this is a chance for a misinformed OP to delete a bad question before it spirals out of control.  Gets them out of a bad spot fairly straightforwardly.

Comment: I don't see how the badge lets them delete a bad question.  I am can see your point with suffrage though.  With disciplined I don't see why it would be needed because the much more likely scenarios are you don't write a bad post, it gets downvoted, or it gets removed.

Comment: Well, the system *lets* the user delete a question.  Our voting allows it to be rated as objectively good or objectively bad.  There's a convention in these parts that a post which is negatively scored must be bad, so it is worth downvoting yet again, so that's the chain reaction I was referring to for the most part.

Comment: I agree and see your point there(one could say this post is a bit of irony) but I still don't get how that relates to the badge.

Comment: Bronze-tier badges are meant to get someone familiar with the site, and are the lowest points of entry when it comes to participation.  On the surface this seems like a huge deal but these actions are actually fairly basic and entry-level for a site like Stack Overflow.  Deleting your own content is something that the site makes simpler by removing a few barriers (and places some stipulations, like you can't have an answer that's positively scored), and so the sooner you learn about this useful feature, the better.